# How to GroupBy/GroupJoin XElements using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am struck with a query. Please help me out.

I have a xml

```
      <Set type="Main">
          <FirstUnit xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
            <CreateDate>2013-06-06T13:19:17.457</CreateDate>
            <PrimaryKey>1</PrimaryKey>
          </FirstUnit>
          <Secondunit  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
            <CreateDate>2013-06-06T13:19:17.457</CreateDate>
            <PrimaryKey>1</PrimaryKey>
            <Exercise>Test</Exercise>
          </SecondUnit>
          <FirstUnit xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
            <CreateDate>2013-06-06T13:19:17.457</CreateDate>
            <PrimaryKey>2</PrimaryKey>
          </FirstUnit>
          <Secondunit  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
            <CreateDate>2013-06-06T13:19:17.457</CreateDate>
            <PrimaryKey>2</PrimaryKey>
            <Exercise>Test</Exercise>
          </SecondUnit>
     </Set>
```

Now all I want is to group the unit based on Primary Key. I.e FirstUnit and SecondUnit should be with `<Primarykey>` node value "1" in one group and the one with `PrimaryKey` node value "2" in another group.

I have tried it with following query, more refining has to be done in it yet,

```
var elements = xDocument.GroupBy(a => a.Elements().Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "PrimaryKey" ).ToList());
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you just need to group by the *value* of those elements:

```
// If <Set> is the document element, change Descendants("Set") to Root
var elements = xDocument.Descendants("Set")
                        .Elements()
                        .GroupBy(x => (int) x.Element("PrimaryKey"));
```

(Supply a namespace for the element if necessary - using a `Where` clause to check just the local name is a bit ugly.)

If this doesn't work for you, please give more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks For your quick reply Jon, I just the output as List<XElement> with two Items. one should have first "FirstUnit" and "SecondUnit". and other should have second "FirstUnit" and "SecondUnit based on primary keys